# Manage memory in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a script with Node.js. When I execute it in the console, it opens and reads a big file and loops over lines in that file.

The problem is that for reading the file, the script allocates 200MB of memory, but for looping over each line, over 1.5 GB is used

In the code, I don't accumulate data in arrays or strings. All the code is in a loop and any variable is overwriting in the next loop.

How can I reduce memory usage? If the problem is in any variable, where I accumulate data, how to detect that?

I didn't share the code, because it's a big script. I only need ways for liberate memory, or detect the memory leak.

**EDIT**

I don't Undrtant why the user delete his aswer... 
This solution work for me. Is a problem with garbage. If I force the GC, that's work!

> node --expose-gc test.js

And then from within the Javascript just do:

> global.gc();

Comment: You don't share the code, neither will StackOverflow.

Comment: You can actually invoke the garbage collector if you think this is related to delayed garbage collection, but most probably it is a memory leak in your script. Double check that you do not leave any event listeners attached to objects that should be disposed etc. Just search for "node.js find memory leak" on any search engine and you will find hundreds of relevant results.

Comment: But general advice would be to read the file line by line, instead of parsing the whole file and then looping over it.

Comment: yes, streaming the file is the way in 99.99% of the cases

Comment: Excuse for don't copy the script. In the script I'm using 7 files, between 100-300 lines of code. If you want, I don't have any problem for copy.

Comment: check heapdump, read the article I linked, and when you've found your bug, stream the file cus that's the way to go ;)

Answer (score 1):

"All code is a loop" it implies you store in memory the whole file, right?
You can try the stream way and read 1 line at time.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');

var instream = fs.createReadStream('your/file');
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  // process line here
});

rl.on('close', function() {
  // do something on finish here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. The problem with the memory used with the big file not is the problem. the problem is with the loop. I'm acumulating memory until block the script.

Comment: I'm not experienced with this kind of problem, but you can try to force the collector https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/

Comment: forcing the GC is also a way to camouflage the problem without knowing its source. Leak hunting is more fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the file. Read https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream . This will reduce the memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for that! But in this case the memory used for the file read noit is the bgi problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to detect memory leaks in Node, one the most useful in my opinion is heapdump.

`npm install heapdump --save`

I enables to write snapshots of the heap at any moment in your program. For example, you could do a dump before and during your file operation using :

```
heapdump.writeSnapshot(function(err, filename) {  
  console.log('dump written to', filename);
});
```

Once you have collected the data, load it inside the profiler in your chrome devTools, and you'll be able to see which variables are hogging memory.

As an alternative, you can follow the [excellent guide on the subject by felixge](https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial) or this [link](https://blog.risingstack.com/finding-a-memory-leak-in-node-js/) which offers a bunch of low level tools in case things get icky.